# Etiqueta form no se muestra completo, una parte queda debajo del footer de la pagina

Tags: html, css, html5, bootstrap-5

El form se "oculta en mi footer, haciendo que no se vea el final del formulario, esto genera un poco de incomodidad a la vista ya que no se termina de entender si finalizo ahi el formulario o hay mas abajo, quisiera que se cierre normalmente, al igual que lo hace arriba, algun consejo? adjunto el html, sin css por que no le modifique nada en especifico al form y una imagen para que se entienda mejor el problema[image: Ahi se ve como la parte del final se esconde bajo el footer]"**

```
<!--Datos de pago-->
<section class="p-4 p-md-5">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-5">
      <div class="card rounded-3">
        <div class="card-body p-4">
          <div class="text-center mb-4">
            <h3>Gestionar pagos</h3>
            <h6>Selecciona forma de pago para proxima cuota (Agosto 2023)</h6>
          </div>
          <form action="">
            <p class="fw-bold mb-4 pb-2">Tarjeta guardada</p>

            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4 pb-1">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="../assets/mastercard-logo.png" />
              <div class="flex-fill mx-3">
                <div class="form-outline">
                  <input type="text" id="formControlLgXc" class="form-control form-control-lg"
                    value="**** **** **** 3193" />
                  <label class="form-label" for="formControlLgXc">Numero de tarjeta</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="fw-bold mb-4">Tambien podes seleccionar otra forma de pago:</p>
            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
              <ul>
                <li><input type="radio" name="formadepago"><a href="https://rapipago.com.ar/rapipagoWeb/"> RapiPago</a></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="formadepago"><a href="https://www.pagofacil.com.ar/"> PagoFacil</a></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="formadepago"><a href="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/"> Mercado Pago</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Guardar preferencias</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ya que es HTML/CSS/JS, no olvides que podés crear un snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para agregar un [repro] en la misma pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo entendido que como tu footer esta en modo fixed no deja ver el contenido del form, entonces quizas puedas agregar un  margin-bottom al div que contiene tu formulario para darle mas espacio y no cubra el borde.

```html
<!--Datos de pago-->
<section class="p-4 p-md-5">
  <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-5">
      <div class="card rounded-3">
        <div class="card-body p-4">
          <div class="text-center mb-4">
            <h3>Gestionar pagos</h3>
            <h6>Selecciona forma de pago para proxima cuota (Agosto 2023)</h6>
          </div>
          <form action="">
            <p class="fw-bold mb-4 pb-2">Tarjeta guardada</p>

            <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4 pb-1">
              <img class="img-fluid" src="../assets/mastercard-logo.png" />
              <div class="flex-fill mx-3">
                <div class="form-outline">
                  <input type="text" id="formControlLgXc" class="form-control form-control-lg"
                    value="**** **** **** 3193" />
                  <label class="form-label" for="formControlLgXc">Numero de tarjeta</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <p class="fw-bold mb-4">Tambien podes seleccionar otra forma de pago:</p>
            <div class="form-outline mb-4">
              <ul>
                <li><input type="radio" name="formadepago"><a href="https://rapipago.com.ar/rapipagoWeb/"> RapiPago</a></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="formadepago"><a href="https://www.pagofacil.com.ar/"> PagoFacil</a></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="formadepago"><a href="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/"> Mercado Pago</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Guardar preferencias</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).